# Distributed transaction using web services on different platforms

Tags: web-services, architecture, integration, distributed-transactions, multiplatform

is it possible to achieve transactionality using web services that are implemented in different technologies?

For example: let's imagine a case where we want to offer an integrated service of 2 different organizations, each of which already have their different systems implemented using different technologies and located in different countries.
Organization A has a Java server exposing Rest services that allow consumers to insert data in a table, then  Organization B has a .Net server exposing Rest services that also allow consumers to insert data in a table. 
Then I want to create a new server to integrate both these services in one, allowing consumers to insert in both organization's databases. So from this new server I have to invoke those 2 rest services in a transactional way (meaning that both organizations will insert or none will insert if there is a failure, it will rollback).

Is that possible to achieve even tho server 1 and server 2 are implemented with different technologies? What if there were n servers all implemented in different technologies and all exposing Rest services?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have real transactions in case of microservice architecture. You have to implement compensations which roll back changes in case of failures. See [Saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) for one of the approaches.

Look at the [Cadence Workflow](https://github.com/uber/cadence) that makes implementing Sagas trivial. [Here is](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/samples/bookingsaga/TripBookingWorkflowImpl.java) an example.

Comment: Hey Maxim, thanks for the reply, my scenario is indeed a Microservices architecture, I hadn't noticed that... Now my google searches are much easier to gather information on this regard.

I have been reading about your proposition of using Saga pattern, it is a nice approach, however I am not sure what you mean with "it is not possible to have real transactions in a microservice architecture". According to some articles a 2PC protocol could work over microservices as well, it is just not recommended because of performance issues but it is possible to implement.

Comment: It is indeed possible to implement distributed transactions. But I wouldn't call the architecture "microservice architecture" after that :). https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=3025012